# Simultaneous touch inputs do not always work

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

In our game, we want the player to reliably tap multiple GameObjects to change their color. Currently it works most of the time. But sometimes it is only registering one of the touch inputs instead of both. We have included a Debug.Log to check the touch count, when we have the problem, only 1 touch is registered even though we are tapping two game objects. The one that does register changes color without a problem but the other one does nothing. Again, this only happens sometimes but is a significant issue to the game play.

This is developed in Unity 5 built to iOS and being tested on 2 different iPhones.

```
void Update () {
     for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
     {
         if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
         {
             RaycastHit2D raycastHit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint((Input.GetTouch(i).position)), Vector2.zero);
             if (raycastHit.collider != null)
             {
                 Debug.Log("Input Manager: " + raycastHit.collider.gameObject.name + "\n Touch: " + i.ToString() +" of " + Input.touchCount.ToString());
             }
 }
```

**We do not have this problem when there are only 2 buttons, but only in the level with 3 buttons.

Comment: Could you make your problem reproduction code smaller, like `for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) { Debug.Log($"Touch #{i + 1} detected."); }` ? Do you get any print outs for two touches versus one?

Comment: I tried swapping in your debug code. I did get print outs for two sometimes but not every time. That's why I'm wondering if iOS and/or Unity can't handle when the touches happen at the exact same moment? This would be a severe limitation but I can't figure out why else it would sometimes see two touches and other times not.

Comment: Are you emulating this with a device on your PC or Mac, or are you pushing your code to a device and testing this? You could simulate multitouch on a device emulator and test for that

Comment: I'm using the UnityRemote5 app on an iPhone 6 while playing from Unity 5.6.6 on Mac.
The touch behavior does still happen when the app has been built to XCode and uploaded to my phone.